# AnsiColor Plugin does not work when ansi string is loaded with getenv

Tags: python, string, batch-file, jenkins, ansi-escape

Setting color from python string works like a charm. Here is a working snippet from my python script:

```
line = "All Tests OK."
print('\033[31m \033[1m' + line + '\033[0m');
```

This results in a *colored* Jenkins Console output like this:

```
All Tests OK.
```

**Extracting ANSI strings from the code:**

To improve code readability, I'd like to move the color strings and escape sequences to a global configuration file. So I have my build.conf.bat batch file which has a bunch of global settings for the build environment and it includes 5 variables for ansiColor like this:

```
set ansiBlue=\033[34m
set ansiRed=...
```

In the Python script I can access all those environment variables by using

```
print(os.getenv('ansiBlue') + " " + line + os.getenv('ansiOff'))
```

This returns a string with the ANSI code, as defined in the batch config file.
Until here, everything is fine but when Jenkins runs the build, the console output is like this:

```
\033[34m All Tests OK. \033[0m
```

So, manually created strings work, but strings from variables don't work. Why that? 
So my question is, what can I do to make those variables work in Jenkins console output?

--

PS: I have already wrapped the concatonated string in a variable which was then stringified with print(str(testOutput)), but this was still no success..

Comment: Python parser translates `\033` to a escape character, but batch parser does not do that translation, so your `os.getenv` reads a backslash and three digits. Maybe something like (sorry, python is not my area) `os.getenv('ansiBlue').replace('\\033', '\033')` could solve your problem.

Comment: `replace` should work, or in general for Latin-1 source text you could use `codecs.decode(source_string, 'unicode_escape')`.

Comment: Thanks guys, the hint with replace() worked although I have never seen the double backslash in the output.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by "@mc nd" the backslash escaped the output somehow and the import from env did not. So a replacing the single backslash with a double backslash worked right now. Thanks!!

```
print(os.getenv('ansiBlue').replace('\\033', '\033') + line + os.getenv('ansiOff').replace('\\033', '\033'));
```

This improves the readablility of the code by factor minus ten. So I externalize the replacement code into a utility file.

```
print(util.ansiBlue + line + util.ansiOff);
```